# CKFinder is not in maven repo

Tags: maven, ckfinder

All!

I have downloaded CKFinder plugin bundled to demo WAR-file to play with it.
But I can not build this sample because maven artifacts listed below can not be found in any maven repositories. Any ideas?

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.ckfinder</groupId>
    <artifactId>CKFinderJava</artifactId>
    <name>CKFinder for Java - Web Application</name>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <url>http://ckfinder.com/</url>
    <organization>
        <name>CKSource - Frederico Knabben</name>
        <url>http://cksource.com</url>
    </organization>
    ...
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>CKFinder</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>CKFinderPlugin-FileEditor</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>${project.groupId}</groupId>
            <artifactId>CKFinderPlugin-ImageResize</artifactId>
            <version>${project.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Commercial software can rarely found in open source repositories :-)

Use [mvn install:install-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-install-plugin/usage.html) or [mvn deploy:deploy-file](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-deploy-plugin/usage.html) to install the JARs and POMs locally.